# Compiled successfully, update not happenning

Tags: apex, batch, dml, update

I have below batch class that is not doing DML update operation also no error in debug log. Can someone please help me here?

Batch class:

```
    global class AckCallUpdatenew implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
        global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
            String query = 'SELECT Id,Name,Account_vod__c,Call_Date_vod__c,ESR_Call__c,Unlock_vod__c FROM Call2_vod__c where ESR_Call__c=null and Recordtype.Name like \'%Sample%\' and Status_vod__c = \'Submitted_vod\'';
            return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
        }


    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Call2_vod__c> scope) {
    List<Call2_vod__c> my_list = new List<Call2_vod__c>();
    List<Account> my_Accounts = new List<Account>();
    Set<Id> s = new Set<Id>();
    List<Call2_vod__c> AckCall= 
            [SELECT  Ack_For_Call_abv__c  
                      FROM Call2_vod__c
                     where  recordtype.Name like '%Acknowledge%'];

   // Set<Id> resultIds = (new Map<Id,Call2_vod__c>(AckCall)).keySet();    
    Set<string> s1 = new Set<string>();  

      for(Call2_Vod__c record:AckCall) {
         s1.add(record.Ack_For_Call_abv__c);
      }           
      for(Call2_vod__c a : scope)
      {
        If(!s1.contains(a.Name))
        {
           if(a.ESR_Call__c==false && a.Call_Date_vod__c+90<date.today())
              {
                 a.Unlock_vod__c=true;
                 a.ESR_Call__c=true;
              // a.Status_vod__c='Saved_vod';

                 my_list.add(a) ; 
                 s.add(a.Account_vod__c);

           }

        }

        else continue;

      //update a;

     }

     update my_list;

     for(Account acc: [select Id,Restrict_Sample_Call__c from Account where Restrict_Sample_Call__c!=true and id=:s])
     {  
        acc.Restrict_Sample_Call__c=true;
        my_Accounts.add(acc);
        System.debug('@saikat@20@'+acc.ID+acc.Restrict_Sample_Call__c);

      }
         update my_Accounts;
       //System.debug('@saikat@20-12@'+my_Accounts[0].ID);

    }   
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }

 }
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that you actually have records in the scope of the execute method (ie, the query in your start method is returning records)?  You might also want to use some debug statements to ensure that your lists within the execute method have records in them.  The list being empty would be a reason why it seems to be working, but no DML happening as the list has no records to act upon.

Comment: There are records.12 Batch runs and runs successfully as Apex job log says.

Comment: There are records in the scope, but are there records in your inner lists that you are building within the execute method?

Comment: But why am I not getting @saikat@20@ in debug log not even any kind of error in debug log?

Comment: I would guess that your debug statement is not showing up in the debug log because the SOQL statement in the for loop doesn't return any records.

Answer (score 3):

I just fixed your formatting and it appears to me that the closing bracket to the below statement is located in the wrong place.

```
     for(Call2_vod__c a : scope)
     {
```

It should be located after this has occurred for each set of locked records:

```
 for(Account acc: [select Id,Restrict_Sample_Call__c from Account where Restrict_Sample_Call__c!=true and id=:s])
 {  
    acc.Restrict_Sample_Call__c=true;
    my_Accounts.add(acc);
    System.debug('@saikat@20@'+acc.ID+acc.Restrict_Sample_Call__c);

  }
     update my_Accounts;
```

Revised code:

```
global class AckCallUpdatenew implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
    {
        String query = 'SELECT Id,Name,Account_vod__c,Call_Date_vod__c,ESR_Call__c,Unlock_vod__c FROM Call2_vod__c where ESR_Call__c=null and Recordtype.Name like \'%Sample%\' and Status_vod__c = \'Submitted_vod\'';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Call2_vod__c> scope) 
    {
       List<Call2_vod__c> my_list = new List<Call2_vod__c>();
       List<Account> my_Accounts = new List<Account>();
       Set<Id> s = new Set<Id>();
       for(Call2_Vod__c record:AckCall) {
          s1.add(record.Ack_For_Call_abv__c);
       }                
       for(Call2_vod__c a : scope)
       {
          If(!s1.contains(a.Name))
          {
             if(a.ESR_Call__c==false && a.Call_Date_vod__c+90<date.today())
                {
                   a.Unlock_vod__c=true;
                   a.ESR_Call__c=true;
              //   a.Status_vod__c='Saved_vod';

                   my_list.add(a) ; 
                   s.add(a.Account_vod__c); // here's what populates s

                }

          }
       }

       update my_list;

       for(Account acc: [select Id,Restrict_Sample_Call__c from Account where Restrict_Sample_Call__c!=true and id=:s])
       { 
          acc.Restrict_Sample_Call__c=true;
          my_Accounts.add(acc);
          System.debug('@saikat@20@'+acc.ID+acc.Restrict_Sample_Call__c);
       }

       update my_Accounts;
     //System.debug('@saikat@20-12@'+my_Accounts[0].ID);

    // *** Need to update Scope Here ***

    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){ 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I have removed continue statement. But where you suggest the end bracket for Call2_vod__c? Can you please place the whole rectified code here?

Comment: Locate it after `update my_Accounts;`

Comment: But my_accounts operates on SOQL results of Account whose IDs match with S Set. How can I locate Scope after my_accounts? Can you please edit my code?

Comment: I just took a closer look at your code again. It appears to me that you're not updating your scope after you update my_Accounts. It's implicit instead of explicit. See the Apex Code Dev docs for more.